# How can I use the information extracted from the textbox in the method LoadMonthlyPayments() and InitializeMyObject()?

Tags: c#

I captured the values from the textboxes :

```
 float.TryParse(textBoxValoareCredit.Text,out float SoldInitial);
 float.TryParse(textBoxDobanda.Text, out float Dobanda);
 float.TryParse(textBoxComisionAnaliza.Text,out float ComisionAnaliza);
 float.TryParse(textBoxAsigurare.Text, out float Asigurare);
 float.TryParse(textBoxComisionLunar.Text, out float Comision);
 int.TryParse(textBoxDurata.Text,out int n);
```

Now,how I can use them in next two function?

```
public void LoadMonthlyPayments()
        {
            MonthlyPayments = new List<MonthlyPayment>();
            
           MonthlyPayment payment=null;
             payment = new MonthlyPayment()
            {
                Luna = 0,
                SoldInitial = 0,
                PlataLunara = 0,
                Dobanda = 0,
                Principal = 0,
                Asigurare = 0,
                Comision = 200,
                TotalLunar = 200,
                SoldCredit=10000,
                
        };
            MonthlyPayments.Add(payment);
            for (int i=1;i<=12;i++)
            { 
               
                MonthlyPayments.Add(InitializeMyObject(i,MonthlyPayments[i-1]));
                
            }
        }
       public MonthlyPayment InitializeMyObject(int i, MonthlyPayment lastMonth)
        {
            
            MonthlyPayment x = new MonthlyPayment();
            x.SoldInitial =Math.Round(lastMonth.SoldCredit,2) ;
            double s = 10000; //Here instead 10000 i want to use 'SoldInitial'
            double a= 0.10 / 100; //Here instead of 9.75 I want to use 'Asigurare'
            double c = (0.5 / 12) / 100; //Here instead of 0.5 I want to use 'ComisionLunar'
            double d = (9.75 / 100) / 12;// Here instead of 9.75 I want to use 'Dobanda'
            return x;

        }
```

How can I use the information extracted from the textbox in the method LoadMonthlyPayments() and InitializeMyObject()?

Comment: In the easiest way, you can pass your values as parameters to your methods.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the variables directly in the TryParse method (i.e. out **float** SoldInitial) they are local to the block in which those methods are coded. If you want access to those variables from another location, you need to declare them as members of the respective object

```
// Declaration of a member variable in the class
    private float SoldInitial;

// ...
// In your method to get the text box values:
float.TryParse(textBoxValoareCredit.Text,out SoldInitial);
// ...
```

You can then use them in the LoadMonthlyPayments method if it is in the same object, or declare the method to have parameters and pass them in via the parameters.